# Create table script for all tables in Postgres db without pg_dump

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Currently I take the approach of using DatabaseMetaData, which is part of JDBC to get metadata and frame a query by appending metadata to string but I doubt its accuracy. Please favour on all possible methods except pgdump as I have restriction on it so unable to do so.

Comment: DatabaseMetadata will not give you enough information to properly reconstruct the DDL for everything in your database. You need to write SQL statements that retrieve the necessary information from the Postgres system catalogs. The best way to get those statements is to use `psql` with the `-E` option that echoes all internal SQL queries, then run the various `\d` commands to see the definition of your tables etc.

Comment: i don't even have psql command line tool. I only use pgadmin to connect to db on cloud :-/ Installations are restricted on corporate system.